# Display content in a new scence when a variable state changes in storyline 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, articulate-storyline

I have manually created a question that has three variables.  The variables are called red, blue or green.  All variables are set to false. When the user selects one or many then clicks the submit button, the user will be sent to a new scene where based on their selections text information will appear.  I have set triggers to change the variable state to true for red, blue and green.  When I select them and click submit I go to the correct scene.  However the choices do not populate.  I tried the choices in different layers and on the base layer.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the order of the triggers is correct, don't send the user away from the first slide before changing the variable value.

Use the arrows in the Triggers pane to re-shuffle the order.

You can see what the current value of the variable is by creating a textbox and writing:

```
%your_varaible_name%
```